# iPad Music app like interface

Tags: ipad, audio-player

I'm making internet radio app for iPad and I was wondering if there are standard or custom implementations of iPad Music app-like interface. I mean thumbnails of albums and when you tap on a thumbnail - cover animation and presenting another controller. Is there something for that? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Nope. There are [bits](http://ericasadun.com/2008/11/one-more-thing-coverflow-updated-for-22/) [and](http://blogs.oreilly.com/iphone/2008/02/coverflow-the-easy-way.html) [pieces](http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.m) of [code](http://fajkowski.com/blog/2009/08/02/openflow-a-coverflow-api-replacement-for-the-iphone/) that don't really work (those are all separate links), but they're a good start for getting something like coverflow working.

Also, you might want to try showing examples of what you have already found in your searching, or any code/UI you've already implemented. Most people on SO are happy to help, but don't take well to 'I haven't put any effort into this yet, please show me all the code I need for my project'.  Even if you *have* put effort in, if you post a 2 sentence question with no demonstrable work, people will assume the worst. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Well, i really didn't know where to start with this thing - i mean do i have to dig into the core animation, or to search for some custom classes or i can go well enough with standard UIKit Views. When i find solution for that - i'll post it here :)

Comment: Try building the basic view of the application first, then add flair bit by bit. UIKit is extremely powerful, you should be able to build all of this using custom views and a little Core Animation.